# win32-loader "The downloaded Release file cannot be trusted"

Tags: linux, windows-10, debian

I have an issue downloading debian via [win32-loader.exe](https://people.debian.org/~rmh/goodbye-microsoft/). I'm on Windows 10 and when I run the installer, the progress bar stops at "Checking GPG signature on release" and it throws  "*The downloaded Release file cannot be trusted! Aborting.*" in normal mode and in expert mode too. I googled for the error message and the only thing I found was [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=133798), which was not helpful at all.

[image]

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

[win32-loader.txt/Readme](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/tools/win32-loader/stable/win32-loader.txt)

Comment: disable firewall or AV suite

Comment: @magicandre1981 did that, didn't really help.

Comment: try to download the ISOs and compare the hashes on your own

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No I didn't, sadly. I had issues repartitioning the windows drive (for dual boot) so I tried going for the windows installer. However, I just ended up using ubuntu instead

Comment: A good workaround, if you really want to use debian, is installing ubuntu and then running debian and a xserver from docker

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full explanation on what the root cause of this issue is.

However I can confirm **I was able to get this installer working** using `win32-loader 0.9.4+deb10u2` with the following *"Base URL for netboot images"*: [http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie`](http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie%60)

I confirmed the above `jessie` mirror fails on`win32-loader 0.10.4 +net +pxe` (although with a different message / reason - looks like a stack overflow funnily enough!)

I did have a theory (read: wildly speculative soothsaying), that perhaps the loader was quite old, and signed with an old version of a key to validate `Release.gpg`. However, looking at the latest release for win32-loader: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/tools/win32-loader/stable/, it looks like it was updated far more recently than `jessie`.

**Update**: just noting that after rebooting, I ran into other issues, so I can't say I recommend this approach, live disc/usb seems far better supported.